# Compatibility between MongoDB BI Connector and ODBC Driver

Tags: mongodb, powerbi

I’m currently working on a project that involves connecting MongoDB to a BI tool using the MongoDB BI Connector and the MongoDB ODBC Driver. I’m wondering if anyone has any information on the compatibility of these tools, or has encountered any issues when using them together.

Here are the versions of the tools I used and it worked:

MongoDB BI Connector version 2.13.1
MongoDB ODBC Driver version 1.2.0 Unicode
I followed this tutorial and it works but I want to know more about the compatibilities.
[https://medium.com/qimi-techblog/connecting-mongodb-hosted-in-mongo-atlas-with-powerbi-including-m0-clusters-ae02fbef0c7d#:~:text=Connecting%20MongoDB%20hosted%20in%20Mongo%20Atlas%20with%20PowerBI,...%206%20Step%206%3A%20Connect%20to%20PowerBI%20](https://medium.com/qimi-techblog/connecting-mongodb-hosted-in-mongo-atlas-with-powerbi-including-m0-clusters-ae02fbef0c7d#:%7E:text=Connecting%20MongoDB%20hosted%20in%20Mongo%20Atlas%20with%20PowerBI,...%206%20Step%206%3A%20Connect%20to%20PowerBI%20)

But I’m wondering why it is not working with newer versions

I’ve done some research on the compatibility of these tools, but I haven’t been able to find any clear answers. I’m wondering if anyone has successfully used these tools together, and could share their experience with me.

Alternatively, if anyone has any information on the compatibility of these tools, or has encountered any issues when using them together, I would greatly appreciate any guidance or advice.

Thank you in advance for your help!

I managed to connect MongoDB to PowerBI using ODBC, but I want to know more about the compatibilities between the BI Connector and the ODBC Driver

This is the error I get if I try to run the 2.14.4 version of the MongoDB BI connector together with 1.1.0 ODBC Unicode driver:
E NETWORK [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:., but could not initialize: unable to connect to MongoDB: no servers available: server selection error: context deadline exceeded, current topology: { Type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, Servers: [{ Addr: cluster0.., Type: Unknown, Average RTT: 0, Last error: connection() error occured during connection handshake: OCSP verification failed: no OCSP cache provided }, { Addr: cluster0......., Type: Unknown, Average RTT: 0, Last error: connection() error occured during connection handshake: OCSP verification failed: no OCSP cache provided }, { Addr: cluster..., Type: Unknown, Average RTT: 0, Last error: connection() error occured during connection handshake: OCSP verification failed: no OCSP cache provided }, ] }

Comment: What do you mean by "But I’m wondering why it is not working with newer versions"? I use the MongoDB BI Connector ODBC Driver version v2.14.5 with local MongoDB version 6.0 and it works fine.

Comment: I tried to use the ODBC Driver version 1.4.0 Unicode together with MongoDB BI Connector version 2.13.1  and it didn't work, I tried to use ODBC Driver version 1.4.0 Unicode with newer versions of MongoDB BI Connector and it also didn't work. That's why I want to know which version of MongoDB BI Connector supports versions of ODBC Driver and vice versa

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work"? Show your configuration and error messages.

Comment: I tried to run the 2.14.4 version of the MongoDB BI connector together with 1.1.0 ODBC Unicode driver and I get this error message:

Comment: E NETWORK [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:., but could not initialize: unable to connect to MongoDB: no servers available: server selection error: context deadline exceeded, current topology: { Type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, Servers: [{ Addr: cluster0.., Type: Unknown, Average RTT: 0, Last error: connection() error occured during connection handshake: OCSP verification failed: no OCSP cache provided }, { Addr: cluster0......., Type: Unknown, Average RTT: 0, Last error: connection() error occured during connection handshake: OCSP verification failed: no OCSP cache provided },

Comment: { Addr: cluster..., Type: Unknown, Average RTT: 0, Last error: connection() error occured during connection handshake: OCSP verification failed: no OCSP cache provided }, ] }

Comment: Please edit your question with such additional information instead of using a comment

Comment: Does the MongoDB run?

Comment: yes it is running

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/bi-connector/current/reference/odbc-driver/#compatibility actually they added a section about the compatibility in the documentation here.